# how to store same id messages in list..?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

`i m new in android development . m working a messages application ...i have retrieved all messages in a "list view but same id/address messages" are showing separately but i wanna store them in a list what should i do..this is snap of my result

```
package com.example.messaging;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Adapter extends BaseAdapter {
    long timeinms;

    private ArrayList<SMS> _data;
    Context _c;

    Adapter (ArrayList<SMS> data, Context c){
        this._data = data;  
        this._c = c;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return _data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return  _data.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)_c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }


        TextView fromView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.address);
        TextView subView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.body);
        // TextView descView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.person);
        // TextView timeView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.date);

        SMS msg = _data.get(position);
        fromView.setText(msg.address);
        subView.setText("Msg:"+(msg.body));

        //timeView.setText(msg.date);   
        //descView.setText("From:"+msg.person);
        return v;
}
}

package com.example.messaging;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class Messaging extends Activity {

ListView msgList;
ArrayList<SMS> listAdapter;
String key_body;
String key_address;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_messaging);



    msgList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listAdapter = new ArrayList<SMS>();
     getSMS();
}

private List<String> getSMS() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    List<String> sms2 = new ArrayList<String>();
     Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/");
        Cursor c= getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null ,null,null);
        startManagingCursor(c);


        // Read the sms data and store it in the list
        if(c.moveToFirst()) {
            for(int i=0; i < c.getCount(); i++) {
                SMS sms = new SMS();
                try{
                    sms.setbody(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body")).toString());
               }
               catch(Exception e){
                Log.i("", "body"+e);
               }

                try{
                     sms.setaddress(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).toString());
               }
               catch(Exception e){
                Log.i("", "address"+e);
           }

               listAdapter.add(sms);

                c.moveToNext();
            }
        }



        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> view, View arg1, int position,
                long arg3) { 
            Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Chat.class);
            String address_key= "msg";
            TextView addr=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.address);
            String address=addr.getText().toString();
            TextView bod=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.body);
            String body=bod.getText().toString();

            intent.putExtra(address_key, address);
            String body_key="msgbody";
            intent.putExtra(body_key, body);
            startActivity(intent);

        }





    return sms2;
    //

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.messaging, menu);
    return true;
}}
```

[image]

Comment: you have to find your text view id in if condition while you are inflating the view.

Comment: also paste your code when you are set adapter to listview.

Comment: now please help me out

Comment: Is this your "Chat" activity in screenshot??

Answer (score 0):

You can check the new id/address with the saved id/address if it is same or is in already existing id/address simple append in the text with the existing one by usine textViewid.append method.